# Cosmos DB trigger is not able to read appsettings using azure functions C#

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

We have implemented COSMOS DB trigger using azure functionv3 . It is not always reading the appsettings. some time it works some times it returns null.

````
    {


        [FunctionName("FilePostProcess")]
        public async Task Run([CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "%cosmos-db-name%",
            collectionName: "%cosmos-cases-container-name%",
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists=true,
            StartFromBeginning=true,
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",
            LeaseCollectionPrefix = "filepostprocess")]IReadOnlyList<Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Document> input,
            [CosmosDB(
                databaseName: "%cosmos-db-name%",
                collectionName: "%cosmos-cases-container-name%",
                ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection")] DocumentClient client,
                 ILogger log, ExecutionContext context)
        {

var enablePostProcessing = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppSettingName");

}```
````

Comment: By appsettings you mean an appsettings.json file or the Function App Settings? Based on the [binding expressions patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns), you should have a setting called `CosmosDBConnection` but the other ones (the ones with `%`) should have names that don't have `%` (for example, `cosmos-db-name`).

Comment: Also please add which is the actual exception or error on runtime.

Comment: Hi,

Problem is on this line 

var enablePostProcessing = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppSettingName");
It works in the local , sometimes it works sometimes it returns empty eventhough we have function appsettings

Comment: So the problem is not on the actual trigger, the trigger is working. Your problem is just on the line inside the Function that reads the environment variable?

Comment: yes, it is problem with environment variable

Answer (score 0):

If you have deployed your function to Azure portal. You should add the settings under Application settings

[image]

If you are testing the function locally, you should add the settings to `local.settings.json` file.

[image]

And you should be able to get the values in the environment variables like this

```
Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AppSettingName");
```

Comment: We are doing as you have mentioned. it works sometimes and again I feel after a new deployment it is not reading the value event though it has value